# how to convert mysqli_stmt_bind_result in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

i want to know what is syntax of `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` in PDO

i need to convert: 
`mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->Expenses );` 
in PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is [`PDOStatement::bindColumn`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php). It is used in a very similar fashion:

```
$stmt->bindColumn('column', $row->Expenses);
```

where `column` is the name of the column in the database.

Comment: suppose i have a query $stmt = $this->vConnection->prepare("SELECT rate FROM $this->tablename where curr=?"); $stmt->bindparam(1, $curr); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bindColumn(1, $row->rate); is this the correct way??

Comment: @user2893428 I'd have thought so. But PDO allows you do to named parameters, which are a whole lot nicer. `$stmt = $this->vConnection->prepare("SELECT rate FROM $this->tablename where curr=:currency"); $stmt->bindparam(':currency', $curr); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bindColumn('rate', $row->rate);`

Comment: thanks alot  lonesomeday . can we use both named parameters and questionmark parameters in the same application??,, actually i have used questionmark at many places so can i now use named at some other places ?

Comment: @user2893428 In the same application, yes. In the same query? You *can*, but I'd strongly advise against it!

Comment: i used named parameter as you answered .$stmt = $this->vConnection->prepare("SELECT rate FROM $this->tablename where curr=:currency"); $stmt->bindparam(':currency', $curr); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bindColumn('rate', $row->rate);    still getting the same error HipHop Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/webApp/services/CurrencyService.php on line 211 at line  $stmt->bindColumn('rate', $row->rate);

Comment: @user2893428 It's really hard to debug someone's database code without having access at least to the code! If you can make it work with number parameters, do so.

Comment: i am having error message HipHop Warning: Creating default object from empty value on  line $stmt->bindColumn('rate', $row->rate);     please help me to identify what is wrong with this scropt !!!